# Use of service-enty in Istio for MESH_INTERNAL communication

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have one question regarding ServiceEntry in Istio.
As I can see in the guides it says that we can use [workloadSelector](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/sidecar/#WorkloadSelector) to select one or more Kubernetes pods of the MESH_INTERNAL to direct traffic into them.
That means that we can route traffic directly to a kuberneted pod without the usage of a kubernetes service?

Let's say for example that meshservice1 wants to call meshservice2.

The below are the labels of meshservice2 pods.

```
kind: Pod
  labels:
    app.name: meshservice2
  name: meshservice2
```

and below is its service-entry

```
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  labels:
    app.name: meshservice2
spec:
  hosts:
    - meshservice2.test
  location: MESH_INTERNAL
  ports:
    - name: http
      number: 80
      protocol: HTTP
  resolution: STATIC
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app.name: meshservice2
```

Is the above two enough to call meshservice2.test succesfully from meshservice1 pods without the definition of a kubernetes svc for memservice2?

I tried it that way, it connects to the other service but I receive 503 response code.
When I add a kubernetes svc for meshservice2 evrything works as expected.

I am just wondering if I can safely discard kubernetes svc from my app for mesh internal calls.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is how it works. meshservice1 sidecar needs to know where to contact meshservice2, it's used Kubernetes service to get the latest endpoint IP of meshservice2 itself.

alternatively, you can use spec.endpoints, but you need to update everytime Pod IP is change.